# Sum in Haskell with two parameter functions

Tags: function, haskell, sum, combinations

I have a function in Haskell that has two parameters and I want to calculate the sum of this function.

```
module Main where

fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n - 1)

combination n p = fact n / fact (n - p)

combSum p = combination p p / foldr1 (\p-> \x -> combination p x) [p,(p-1)..0]

prob p = combination p p / combSum p
```

That not seems to work. The combSum function. How can I write that function?

Just correcting the function... Sorry...

x must vary from p to 0.

Comment: `\x -> p` → `\x -> \p`?

Comment: Sorry... I think I made a mistake...

Comment: `\p -> \x -> combination p x` is equivalent to `combination`. I think the problem is probably `[p,(p-1)..0]`; try `combSum p = combination p p / foldr1 (flip combination) [0..p]`.

Comment: Permutations are defined as `permutations n k = fact n \`div\` fact (n - k)`. Combinations are defined as `combinations n k = permutations n k \`div\` fact k`. You're naming your functions wrong. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Also, `permutations n n` is simply `fact n` because `fact (n - n)` is `fact 0` which is simply `1`. Hence `permutations n n` is `fact n \`div\` 1` which is simply `fact n`.

Comment: Oh, and your `prob` function can be rewritten as `prob p = foldr1 permutations [p,(p-1)..0]`.

Comment: I'll fix the name to permutations... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
combination p p
```

is the same thing as:

```
fact p
```

Next, I am not entirely sure what your combSum does. Especially the denominator. foldr takes a function, *an initial value*, and a list. I dont see your initial value. Are you just trying to sum a series of values? like

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
combination n p = fact n / fact (n - p)
combSum p = sum $ map (\x -> combination p x) [p, p-1 .. 0]
prob p = fact p / combSum p
```

Not sure if that is what you want ...

Comment: `foldr` takes an initial value. `foldr1` does not. See: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr1

Comment: Also a combination is defined as `combinations n p = permutations n p \`div\` fact p`. A permutation is defined as `permutations n p = fact n \`div\` fact (n - p)`. Please don't mix them.